# web.config rewrite rule: rewriting from one query string to another which contains the first

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string

I have a problem as follows:

I want to rewrite from /index.php?jobs to /index.php?retail-jobs-in-london

and I tried the following rule:

```
<rule name="jobs" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="index.php$" />
   <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="jobs" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://www.domain.com/index.php?retail-jobs-in-london" />
</rule>
```

However, I get an error for the intended page /index.php?retail-jobs-in-london, I believe because "jobs" is in the query string for the intended page, so it tries to loop.

How can I explicitly look for a query string which is exactly and only "jobs"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

Change this line so the regex matches the start and end of the string:

`<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^jobs$" />`

Or you could change it to match only if it starts with "jobs", which would handle when other things have been added to the end:

`<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^jobs" />`

Comment: Many thanks for speedy answer - this what I needed. So fast I can't yet accept your answer!